# Is there a way to move data from a vector to a dynamic array?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I use `std::vector` to do allocation for me in a function.When I'm done, I want to get plain data from it without extra copying. The data ptr will be handled by another class, so I can ditch the vector and I don't have to care if it's valid. Basically, I want to transfer ownership of vector's data. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It may contain a very large amount of serialized graph data

Comment: If you're asking if there is a way to "detach" a vector's internal buffer pointer and send it on its merry way to your own nefarious deeds, *no*. Furthermore, it was allocated with the vector's allocator, so unless you destroyed it with said-same, you're skating on thin ice even if it *were* possible.

Comment: @WhozCraig, you are right and i realized that my logic is incorrect after posting my answer. Anyway I have deleted my post.

Comment: Thanks, I will have to rewrite this piece then.

Comment: If you fear about some bytes of memory the vector still needs for data management, then you may also fear by having more code to handle your data manually. Using the data from pointer vec.data() is valid code. So if your vector is alive and the data is not changed through the vector, you can operate on it. If you only want to prevent your code from copying data, use move operations or reference. There is no way to kidnap the data of stl containers anyway. Maybe you can give us a hint, which is your basic problem. Getting the data buffer looks like the solution :-)

Comment: But is there any "array builder" class implementation that can free the pointer when you're done building the array?

Comment: Klaus, I'm experimenting with serialization and I want my function to return a data handle which handles a byte array, so I can have a simple interface without vector's extra stuff.

Comment: @Semyon95 No, but you could always roll your own.

Comment: What is the BASIC problem. That a vector has a lot of 'extra' stuff is ok, but it comes without any cost, if it is not used. A template method will not be instantiated, if it is not used. The size of extra data for data management is quite low. You can simply check it with sizeof(vector<X>). So why you want to throw the vector away? Serialization sounds like steaming? Is std::i/ostream a better interface? ostrstream maybe?

Comment: @Klaus, you're right, I think I will wrap my class around std::vector and move the vector into it, then just interpret the data as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Transferring ownership is not possible by design of `std::vector`. However you may extend the lifetime of the vector by making it `static` and just using the pointer to the first element:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int* getData()
{
    static std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(0);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    return v.data(); // pointer to first element, equivalent to &v.front() or &v[0]
}

int main()
{
    auto data = getData();
    for ( std::size_t i(0); i < 4; ++i )
    {
        std::cout << data[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/hsrOeH

As the vector is `static`, the destructor isn't called at the end of scope (which is the end of the method `getData()`). Hence it is safe to use the pointer returned by `.data()` outside of this scope.

Comment: You may want to `clear` the vector before calling `push_back`. Otherwise, the vector will get bigger every time `getData` is called.

Comment: @FredOverflow Well the whole idea of doing stealing the pointer is idiotic. Calling this method (as it is right now) would invalidate the previous pointer. But `clear` and `push_back` does the same thing. It's unsafe. The correct way would be to have a reference to the vector in the class obviously